# Unknown mapping is experienced when running webapp

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets, web-applications

I am trying to map my first login page using controller in spring maven on eclipse. I mapped '/login' to login.jsp file in my WEB-INF/jsp folder. But on calling the url localhost:8080/Project/login it is giving 404 error with this message:

> /Project/WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp
>
> Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView: name 'hello'; URL [/WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'project'

I don't have any file named hello.jsp nor did I map to any such file. My code is as below: ProjectController.java

```
package com.fico;    
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController;

@Controller
public class ProjectController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getLogin(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        ModelAndView in = new ModelAndView("login");
        in.addObject("message", "Finally page loaded");
        return in;
    }
}
```

web.xml file:

```
<web-app id = "WebApp_ID" version = "2.4"
   xmlns = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
   
  <display-name>Spring MVC Project</display-name>
  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>project</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
         org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>project</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>  
</web-app>
```

project-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.fico" />
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

login.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType = "text/jsp; charset = UTF-8" %>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Hello World</title>
   </head>
   
   <body>
      <h2>${message}</h2>
   </body>
</html>
```

Why is it searching for hello.jsp file? I dont understand. Is there any mistake in my mapping or controller? I check the file structure, no problem in any. I added all the dependencies as needed. The default welcome page is loading fine. It is also working if I add a hello.jsp file. Why is it happening?

Comment: Have you debug the controller to make sure is getting in /login?

Comment: > DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'project' processing GET request for [/Project/login]. I wrote a print statement in that function but it is not executed

Comment: I do not meant this. I meant to place a break point in your login controller to be sure is getting there. If you are not debuging place a syso _system.out.println("I have been in the controller before rendering login.jsp")

Comment: You must have possibly mixed up different projects unknowingly. Debug your app as Kimy82 suggested. You may also clean and redeploy the project to be sure your IDE is not running the application in its previous deployment state. Yea, its possible. Some IDEs can act funny.

Comment: Read the last statement of my comment. That print statement is not getting executed. That means it is not going into it.

Comment: Don't know how but it is working now!! Yes, I made no changes to the code. Shutdown the system for a night and first time I hit run in the morning it worked. I guess eclipse is messing with me -_-